# Maximum size limit restriction of MIT App Inventor project

Tags: android, app-inventor

I created an app in **MIT App Inventor**, but it says "**Build failed! Sorry, can't package projects more than 5 MB.** **yours is 14 Mb.**"

What is causing this problem?
Is it possible to fix this? If so how?

**Background**

My project is a city guide, which has details about city like shops, hospitals, general stores etc. I took the all visiting cards and scanned it and attached the picture to its desired name.

Comment: Switch to Eclipse or Android Studio. Those IDE's don't have such silly restrictions.

Comment: [How to overcome the App Inventor project limit of 5 MB](http://puravidaapps.com/filebyfile.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Inventor has a 5MB limit on how big your AIA file can be

(http://twodogapps.com/?page_id=686#MakingAIA Click here).  This has to do with how the build server handles projects,

and while you may be able to get by with a file that’s bigger, the likelihood is that your project won’t compile every time.  Reducing the size of an AIA file really isn’t that difficult.  Of course, the answer to the main question here is that you have to reduce the size of that AIA… But how?

First, what are assets?  They’re pictures, sounds, videos, graphics etc. that you’ve added to your project.

**Too Voluminou**s – If you have uploaded many, many assets to your project, you’ll have to remove some of them, or use the other techniques mentioned below.  Do you really need all of those assets?  Try to reuse items if you can.

**Too Big** – This is a pretty simple item… you have a 5MB limit, and App Inventor takes at least 1.5 of those megabytes just to work.  If you add a 7MB video, your project will fail.  But, you say, “I need that video!”  The best way to handle this is to load the video from the web the first time the app runs.  Taifun and Hossein have solutions on the App Inventor forum on how to do this.  Rather than include the video with the APK, download it when the app first runs.

For More Info Check this 
http://twodogapps.com/?page_id=686#ShrinkingAIA